# check multiple events - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Suppose I want to run a function `myFunction` at each of the events `$(document).ready`, `$(sometag).on('click',....)`. How can I construct a function that checks if any of those two events are triggered, and then run the method. Can I pass `$(document)` as an argument and then check `$(document).isReady` or check `$(document).click(function(e){if (e.target.is($(some tag))) ...})`. Is this correct ?

Comment: `if (e.target.is('div'))`

Comment: @ArunPJohny should be `$(e.target).is`, remember that `e.target` is a DOM element reference (guess you may have forgotten that for an instant `;)`).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté missed that...

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to understand what the heck you are talking about, but it sounds like you're trying to attach an event handler *and* trigger it on document ready, and if so you'd do that like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(sometag).on('click', function() {
        // do stuff
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Excuse me if I am not clear. In fact, I don't want to repeat myself. I want to run some function when either of two events are triggered : `document is ready` `some tag is clicked`

Comment: @user1611830 - And that is exactly what this does !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
function myFunc(event) {
    if (event.type == 'ready')
        console.log('It is a document.ready');
    else if (event.type == 'click')
        console.log('It is a click');
}
$(document).on('ready', myFunc).on('click', 'a', myFunc);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dNbR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

from what i could understand from your question...

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/eR4wG/1/

```
$('.checkbox').change(function (e) {
    if (e.isTrigger) {
        alert('not a human');
    } else {
        alert("manual check by human");
    }
});

$('.checkbox').trigger('change'); //alert not a human because it is automatically triggered.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question very much, but try this:

```
$(function(){
   $('div1,div2,#id1,#id2,.class1,.class2').click(function(){
      // do something
      yourFunction();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

triggering function on multiple events of an element, you may try:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function() {
    ...
});
```

and multiple function on multiple elements, try:

```
$('#element #element1 #element2').on('keyup keypress blur change', function() {
    ...
});
```